# PowerShell Json Serialization to interop with Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, powershell

I want to interop PowerShell with Java.  That is, I want to call a PowerShell script from Java and receive back objects.

I can launch the PowerShell in a separate process and capture the output as demonstrated in [Invoke Powershell scripts from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147634/invoke-powershell-scripts-from-java).

To transfer objects from one process to another, I want to serialize them in a Json format.

Is there a PowerShell command to turn an object into a JSON formatted string, or do I need to reach for a .NET object to do this as shown in [JSON Serialization/Deserialization in PowerShell](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/json-serializationdeserialization-in-powershell/)?

Will the Microsoft JSON interop with Java JSON packages?

Is there a better solution than JSON?  E.g. XML serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is the convertTo-json cmdlet in PS V3  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849922.aspx

Comment: Great.  Any experience deserializing the result in Java with the GSON library?