# Can we execute windows Azure PowerShell using Java code

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I tried searching for same on net but was not able to find anything useful.
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147634/invoke-powershell-scripts-from-java) and [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d32537bd-0aef-440e-8760-6b3085390c37/executing-powershell-script-via-java?forum=winserverpowershell) link but they both talk about only PowerShell and not Azure PowerShell.

I still tried it and got following error

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>powershell.exe Get-AzureVM
>   Get-AzureVM : The term 'Get-AzureVM' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-AzureVM
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureVM:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the module for Windows Azure wasn't loaded. Try creating a script file (vm.ps1) with the following:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1"
Get-AzureVM
```

And then run it like this (assuming you saved it on your C: drive):

```
powershell.exe C:\vm.ps1
```

Comment: Hi Sandrino. Thanks you for pointing that out. It is working properly now. Just need to find a way to execute it using Java now.

Answer (score -1):

If your ultimate goal is to manage/automate Azure resources by using Java code or to build Java apps with Azure services, you may wish to review the [**Microsoft Azure SDK for Java**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/).