# Are there any API's exposed for SCVMM 2012 which can be accessed via Java?

Tags: java, hyper-v

I want to monitor the states of VM created using Hyper-V/SCVMM using the Java code.
I have read that for Hyper-V i need to use J-Interop to acess the API of Hyper-V.
Does SCVMM also provides API to get the basic information of VM ? If yes then is there any documentation to access it via Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want in Java only? I know there are some java libraries available but they are not reliable. I have tried but most them lacks many feature and are buggy. I have done in python and VB !

Comment: Yes i want it in Java only. PowerShell seems the only option for now. Please share the link/name of java library. Ill see how much useful are they.

Answer (score 0):

I had posted same question on Microsoft forum and got following answer.

THE SCVMM API is PowerShell.
Unless you want to also install Service Provider Foundation (SPF) in front for a web service.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/8545d105-bc46-46e8-83d1-704c477d4915/are-there-any-apis-exposed-for-scvmm-2012-which-can-be-accessed-via-java?forum=virtualmachinemanager#8545d105-bc46-46e8-83d1-704c477d4915

Following link are helpful  :
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d32537bd-0aef-440e-8760-6b3085390c37/executing-powershell-script-via-java?forum=winserverpowershell

[Invoke Powershell scripts from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147634/invoke-powershell-scripts-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

**In reply of the comment** 
"Hi Reuben. SCVMM 2007 onward the only API provided is Power Shell and not WMI. Please refer : social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/… "

**Couldn't add this much long comment so posting it in Answer:**

Saw the link and as usual the guy David has not answered the last question.

I have worked on Hyper-V 2,3 on both WinServer 2k8 & 2012 and we have used WMI. I couldn't agree with the comment, "The public interfaces for SCVMM 2007 and SCVMM 2008 are all PowerShell. There are no WMI interfaces. "

Read this msdn link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377(v=vs.85).aspx

They have written that , "Windows PowerShell provides a simple mechanism to connect to Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) on a remote computer"

So If I can directly acces WMI using j-interop or j-integra then why do I need powershell ?

Just Read about [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) in wiki.

Any how its up to you , how you wanna develop. But What I think is its an extra work and extra process you are gonna trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Reuben. I will try and let you know how it goes.
I hope you have live ID. You can add same comment there also. It would be great help for all.

Comment: Yeah sure I will ask them !

Comment: I just checked the documentation of SCVMM 2012 here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg610610.aspx

The only reference for API i found was for powershell cmdlets and there is no documentation provided for WMI.

For Hyper-V .. yes .. WMI documentation is provided. But
for SCVMM ...  no .. WMI documentation not provided. Only powershell documentation provided.

Please check and let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: oh my gosh !!! Extremely my fault , Unintentionally writing every posts I assumed Hyper-V . Deleting my other posts. Thank you very much for this good discussion and +5 for your research and hard work.

But again, executing powershell from java will be poor in efficiency !

Comment: np :) ... I know executing PowerShell from Java is bad idea but Microsoft have not provided any other choice. And yes .. good discussion :)