# getTotalSpace() with UNC

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to use `File.getTotalSpace()` and `File.getFreeSpace()` on a NAS share via UNC, from a Windows host.

Due to the various links in the NAS, the free/total space will be different based on the specific directory requested.

For example, in a DOS box:

```
dir \\nas\level1
```

might return 12,234,567 bytes free, but:

```
dir \\nas\level1\level2\level3
```

returns 987,654,321 bytes free.

I try:

```
new File("\\\\nas\\level1\\level2\\level3").getFreeSpace();
```

but this returns 12,234,567.  It appears that `getFreeSpace()` and `getTotalSpace()` are retrieving the reported space from the root of the path (\\nas, in this case), rather than from the level I requested.

If I map that UNC path to a drive letter, e.g.:

```
net use s: \\nas\level1\level2\level3
```

then

```
new File("s:").getFreeSpace();
```

will return the correct value.  But I have to iterate through a bunch of UNC paths, so mapping them all is not feasible.

So how can I get the free/total space of a UNC-based share from the specific directory level I'm requesting?

Comment: Suggestion: try java.nio [FileStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/class-use/FileStore.html).  For example, `Files.getFileStore(Paths.get("path to file").toRealPath()).getUsableSpace();`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it produced the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get the expected space used/space free values from Windows explorer.

If so, you should also be able to get these same values programmatically from WMI.

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Use a [Java::WMI library or wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java) like [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/).
2. Write a simple VBScript or [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159341/how-to-get-disk-capacity-and-free-space-of-remote-computer) script, then [call your script from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147634/invoke-powershell-scripts-from-java).

Here's a simple PowerShell (.ps1) example, from the above link:

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName remotecomputer -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" |
Foreach-Object {$_.Size,$_.FreeSpace}
```

Here's another example:

https://superuser.com/questions/911534/determine-the-size-of-a-network-folder

```
$startFolder = "\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out those options.

Comment: The first script above seems to only work with physical or logical devices (drive letters) on a remote machine.  The second looks like it would work to retrieve used space, but not space available or total space.  Am I missing something?